# Having trouble setting up Eclipse for android development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide, apk

I need to set up a workspace in eclipse to edit an APK so that I can mod it. I have the decompiled and deobfed java sources but I have never done this before, and I can't get eclipse working with android. I have installed the sdk and the software for eclipse, but I have some errors after creating a new basic project. Here are some of the many errors, Probably stemming from 1 problem that I just cant figure out.

XML:

Error in an XML file: aborting build.

\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Among many, many more XML errors that look similair.

Java:

ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type

R cannot be resolved to a variable

The import android.support cannot be resolved

The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity

There are definitely some jars that should be in the build path that are not there, but I don't know why they aren't there and what is missing. I probably set it up wrong but I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and that did not help.

Sorry for the shitty formatting I have no idea how to format and this is my first question on here sorry!

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for several years now.

Comment: is Intellij supported? If not what is?

Comment: I really like eclipse so if there is any way to use it that would be great.

Comment: Android Studio is the only supported IDE [tag:android-studio]